# Post ajax request doesn't reach php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn ajax with jquery but my script doesn't seem to work
I used the form to see if there is any issue with the script.php file but it's working fine.
When I click the sendAjax button nothing happens.I check the network tab in dev tools on firefox and nothing appears to be send.
I also tried to send the data json style but not working also {'data':'Data'}
Even if I echo something on the php script doesn't work.
I think is just a stupid mistake but as this is my first ajax script I have a hard time finding it

Here are my scripts.
index.html  jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sendAjax").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "script.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                dataStr: 'Content'
            },
            succes: function (response) {
                alert("merge");
            }


        });
    });
});
```

index.html html

```
<div id='container'>
    <form action='script.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' placeholder="name">
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" name='button' value="SendForm" id='button'>
    </form>
    <button id='sendAjax'>Send</button>
</div>
```

script.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

Comment: maybe success instead of succes?

Comment: its a typo. `succes`

Answer (score 0):

```
succes: function (response) {
  alert("merge");
}
```

Change to

```
success: function (response) {
   alert("merge");
}
```